# Explaining vector math for a pendulum camera

Tags: unity, mathematics, vector, quaternion

I came across a code that I guess is doing a pendulum camera, that's the class name. I would like to know the math behind that.  I would like also to know how to decipher those stuff in game math, what are your recommendations ? I already own the book 3D Math for computer graphics by lengyel, but those stuff are not explained there.

```
        Vector3 r = transform.right;
        Vector3 u = transform.up;
        Vector3 v = transform.forward;

        Vector3 dir = v + u * Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime * 0.01f)  + r * Mathf.Sin(Time.deltaTime *0.01f + 0.1f) * -0.1f;
        dir.Normalize();

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        rotation.SetLookRotation(dir, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Comment: If you ignore what they do, sin/cos functions basically go up to 1 and down to -1 continuously. Time gives a constant change. Sin and cos are basically what you use when you want things to bob back and forth staying within a constrained space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three component vectors `right`, `up`, and `forward` probably point along the axes `x`, `y`, and `z` relative to the camera.  So by adding these vectors together you can compose any other vector.  It works the same as if you built a vector by specifying its three elements individually, except that you are adding three vectors which each have one non-zero element.  Normlizing that sum guarantees that the total length of the sum is a vector of length 1.

If `Time.deltatime` is the time since last update then, except for small variations, `dir` will be not vary from frame to frame.  It's essentially taking the sine and cosine of constant values, which yields a constant camera direction.  If that time value were accumulated rather than constant, then this would yield a circular motion of the camera.  On the x-y plane, the `x` and `y` coordinates could be specified by taking the sine and cosine of a single angle.  Your code sample appears to be doing that, using `Time.deltatime` as its angle (but I think it's doing it wrongly, as it's essentially constant each frame).

This picture is loosely related, please ignore the complex part; I was just trying to find an animation of [the unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

[image: The most interesting trigonometry wave gif I could find]

Comment: how one vector dir is composed into 3 components v+ u*cos(theta) + r*sin(theta) into the equation in the code ?

Comment: Guessing from their names, each of those components is orthogonal to the others.  So they could be combined to produce any direction, and the following call to `Normalize` would turn it back into a unit vector.

Comment: could you explain more please, about if vectors are orthogonal how can they be used a one direction vector ?

Comment: I will try to edit that into my answer.  You might also consider visiting [chat] for back-and-forth questions.

Answer (score 1):

He's trying to oscillate between `V` and `V+U*0.01+R*0.1`, I think. If you want to visualize, it is trying to do something like the picture below:

[image]

The arrow at the top represents the path `DIR` will take as time proceeds and it will go back to `V` when the `sin` value becomes zero. The summation, just adds the 'perturb' effect to the `DIR` vector, so that it doesn't always end up as `V`.

Comment: Yeah, `V` is the 'U`' that's pointing up in the picture:). That was a typo when I made the picture.